# I am trying to create a script that runs consecutive prop.test( ) for consecutive values using a for Loop

Tags: r

```
Script:
a    <-     c(10, 20)  
b    <-      c(100, 200)  
c    <-     c(50 , 1000)  
d    <-      c(3000, 4300)   

for (i in c(a,b,c,d))
{
print(prop.test(a,b))
}.
```

So essentially I want every 2 objects to be paired up. I hope I am somewhat clear.

Comment: I want a prop test(a ,b) then prop.test(c,d). I am not interested in prop.test(b,c). I do plan to add more objects such as e and f. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the vectors in a list and use a `for` loop as follows -

```
list_data <- list(a, b, c, d)

result <- vector('list', length(list_data)/2)
for(i in seq_along(result)) {
  n <- (i -1) * 2 + 1
  result[[i]] <- prop.test(list_data[[n]], list_data[[n+1]])
  print(result[[i]])
}
```